# Use mpl::vector as function table

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-mpl

I am writing some C++ that reads an XML string and populates some struct members with values matching attribute keys in the XML file. At the moment, the first pass at this makes a stl::unordered_map of key - value pairs. The next step is to interpret the value strings and return them as their destination types to be stored in the structs. Some of the types are a bit complicated but I have methods that can convert them.

What I want to do is use an mpl::vector to map the keys to the struct members using the get_value_* methods to convert the values. I think it will look a bit like:

```
typedef boost::mpl mpl;
using namespace std;

template<string K, typename T, T& dest, boost::function<void(MapTypePtr, string, T& dest)> >
struct MapperRow {};

struct Mapper : mpl::vector<
    MapperRow < "death_star_radius", Length, death_star.radius, get_value_units >,
    MapperRow < "death_star_energy", Energy, death_star.energy, get_value_units >,
    MapperRow < "operational",       bool,   death_star.operational, get_value_simple >,
    MapperRow < "num_tie_fighters",  int,    death_star.tie_fighers, get_value_simple >
> {};
```

The Length and Energy types are typedefs of boost::units::quantities.

Is this doable with boost metaprogramming? If I'm on the right track, how do I make it run? Do I need to iterate mpl::vector?

Comment: I don't understand the question yet, but you can't use classes like strings in the template declaration the way you do. That only works with basic types like 'bool' or 'unsigned'.

Comment: There might be an mpl wrapper type that does it somehow? I might be asking the impossible but I've seen something similar with boost state machines so I'm hoping I can get close.

Comment: Yes, there are ways. Not pretty tough (use a template that has many characters as arguments). For this I found it's often easier to use a code generator which might be simple in your case because you already have the XML and only need an xsl or some other kind of translator to generate the code.

Comment: `struct death_star_radius { const char* value() { return "death_star_radius"; } };` type stuff can be used to represent a string as a type.  In C++11, `struct { const char* value() { return "death_star_radius"; } }` as an anonymous type also works.  Sadly, string literals cannot be used as direct template arguments as far as I know.

Comment: This article http://cpp-next.com/archive/2012/10/using-strings-in-c-template-metaprograms/  provides some insight into using strings within template metaprograms.

Comment: Since you read the keys from a file, how do you expect to use them as template arguments? You would need some sort of switch for "converting" the runtime value to a compile-time value, which would defeat the purpose of having a map in the first place. Well, you could also achieve your goal by iterating at compile-time over the map to find the key corresponding to the runtime value, but is it really worth the trouble?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitively possible (see below), but I'm not sure it's worth the trouble... Couldn't you use a simpler approach, perhaps with inheritance and polymorphism?

Nevertheless, here is a working solution using Boost.MPL:

```
// MapperRow holds the necessary parsing informations: type of the member,
// type of the object, pointer to the appropriate member, parsing function
template<typename Type, typename Clazz, Type Clazz::*Member, 
         void (*Parser)(const std::string &, Type &)>
struct MapperRow
{
    typedef Type type;
    typedef Clazz clazz;
    typedef Type Clazz::*memberType;
    static const memberType member;
    typedef void (*parserType)(const std::string &, Type &);
    static const parserType parser;
};

template <typename Type, typename Clazz, Type Clazz::*Member,
          void (*Parser)(const std::string &, Type &)>
const typename MapperRow<Type, Clazz, Member, Parser>::memberType
    MapperRow<Type, Clazz, Member, Parser>::member = Member;

template <typename Type, typename Clazz, Type Clazz::*Member,
          void (*Parser)(const std::string &, Type &)>
const typename MapperRow<Type, Clazz, Member, Parser>::parserType
    MapperRow<Type, Clazz, Member, Parser>::parser = Parser;


// fill iterates over a map key->MapperRow, trying to find the given key.
// if found, it calls the parsing function, otherwise it asserts false (should
// probably throw an exception instead)
template <typename Clazz, typename First, typename Last>
struct fill_impl
{
    static void apply(Clazz &obj, const std::string &key,
                      const std::string &value)
    {
        typedef typename mpl::deref<First>::type entry;
        static const char *curKey = 
            mpl::c_str< typename 
                mpl::first<entry>::type
            >::value;

        if (key == curKey)
        {
            typedef typename mpl::second<entry>::type Row;

            Row::parser(value, obj.*Row::member);
        }
        else
        {
            fill_impl<
                Clazz, typename
                mpl::next<First>::type,
                Last
            >::apply(obj, key, value);
        }
    }
};

template <typename Clazz, typename Last>
struct fill_impl<Clazz, Last, Last>
{
    static void apply(Clazz &obj, const std::string &key,
                      const std::string &value)
    {
        assert(false && "key not found");
    }
};

template <typename Map, typename Clazz>
void fill(Clazz &obj, const std::string &key, const std::string &value)
{
    fill_impl< 
        Clazz, typename 
        mpl::begin<Map>::type, typename 
        mpl::end<Map>::type
    >::apply(obj, key, value);
}
```

Sample use:

```
template <typename T>
void get_value_units(const std::string &str, T &value)
{
    value = T::from_value(boost::lexical_cast<typename T::value_type>(str));
}

template <typename T>
void get_value_simple(const std::string &str, T &value)
{
    value = boost::lexical_cast<T>(str);
}

typedef boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::energy> Energy;
typedef boost::units::quantity<boost::units::si::length> Length;

struct DeathStar
{
    Length radius;
    Energy energy;
    bool operational;
    int tie_fighters;
};

// Could be clearer with MPLLIBS_STRING*
typedef mpl::map<
    mpl::pair<
        mpl::string<'deat','h_st','ar_r','adiu','s'>, 
        MapperRow< Length , DeathStar, &DeathStar::radius, 
                   &get_value_units<Length> > >,
    mpl::pair<
        mpl::string<'deat','h_st','ar_e','nerg','y'>,
        MapperRow< Energy, DeathStar, &DeathStar::energy, 
                   &get_value_units<Energy> > >,
    mpl::pair< 
        mpl::string<'oper','atio','nal'>, 
        MapperRow< bool, DeathStar, &DeathStar::operational, 
                   &get_value_simple<bool> > >,
    mpl::pair< 
        mpl::string<'num_','tie_','figh','ters'>, 
        MapperRow< int, DeathStar, &DeathStar::tie_fighters, 
                   &get_value_simple<int> > >
> death_star_map;

int main()
{
    DeathStar ds;
    fill<death_star_map>(ds, "death_star_radius", "12");
    fill<death_star_map>(ds, "death_star_energy", "34");
    fill<death_star_map>(ds, "operational", "1");
    fill<death_star_map>(ds, "num_tie_fighters", "56");

    std::cout << "Radius: " << ds.radius << '\n';
    std::cout << "Energy: " << ds.energy << '\n';
    std::cout << "Operational: " << std::boolalpha << ds.operational << '\n';
    std::cout << "Tie fighters: " << ds.tie_fighters << '\n';
}
```

* [MPLLIBS_STRING](http://abel.web.elte.hu/mpllibs/metaparse/MPLLIBS_STRING.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No it's not worth the trouble but for me it seemed like something that should be possible and would help me understand mpl. I will mediate on your answer and see if I achieve enlightenment!